# How to transfer erc20 tokens from a smart contract?

Tags: solidity

I sent some tokens (Token-A) to the contract address of another token (Token-B) by mistake instead of sending the tokens to my wallet address. I am the deployer of Token-B so I know I should be able to get the Token-A that I sent by mistake out somehow but I don't know what to do...

How do I transfer token A *from* the contract of token B *to* my wallet address? I know I need to send ETH to my token's contract so it has gas for the transaction, but then what? How do I tell the smart contract to transfer an erc20 token that it holds in it's balance to my wallet? I'm sure it's a simple process but I can't seem to find the answer anywhere.

Comment: Don’t send ether anywhere , what are u saying is wrong.

Comment: Even if u are the deployer of Token-B , if u don’t have a method to transfer extra token already implemented in it then the tokens are stuck.

Comment: If you didnt specifically implement a function to withdraw tokens sent to the contract theyre stuck forever, being the deployer/owner wont help you there. And dont send ether, its going to get stuck as well